# symfony + Apiplatform. How to validate the format of a Date type filter?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

What is the best method to validate the correct format of a Date type filter :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Groups("read")
 * @ApiFilter (DateFilter::class)
 */
 protected $dateAdded;
```

If I pass a value of type string no error is thrown and the parameter is simply ignored.
How do I send an error message back to API users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add assert Date

```
 /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetimetz")
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\Date()
         */
        private $date;
```

Comment: Assert validates the addition but not the fact that the filter is in the correct format.